# NodeJS error on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js

I installed NodeJS and used it normally, but after restarting my computer, this error appeared.

I searched, and was told that I have to fix my `NODE_PATH` environment variable, but that didn't work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I recommend enclosing the actual errors inside of your question, rather than screenshots of prompts. It is really difficult to figure out what's going wrong, and most people will completely ignore your question. That's why you haven't gotten an answer for 9 hours. Downvote until you fix and provide better error details.

Answer (score 2):

The error you are seeing is happening inside of the gulp-jshint module. Most likely, your node_modules directory is corrupt. You should delete it, and re-create it via `npm install`. I recommend closing the Dropbox application on your computer before trying this, as it is possible it will mistakenly restore the files.